# Putting Google Maps Street View in Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, sidebar, google-street-view

I am trying to add the [Google Maps Street View API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) to my sidebar. I created a div with an id for the map, but when I load the website it does not show.

This is my code so far:

```
 var panorama;
        function initialize() {
        console.log("I am in the Google Maps function")
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('google-maps'),
            {
                position: {lat: 37.803012, lng: -122.270312},
                pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
                zoom: 1
            });//END initialize
        console.log("I am leaving the Google Maps function")
        }
```

This is the code for my sidebar:

```
function initializeSidebar(map) {
        var popup = map.infoWindow;
        //when the selection changes update the side panel to display the popup info for the
        //currently selected feature.
        popup.on("SelectionChange", function() {
          displayPopupContent(popup.getSelectedFeature());
        });
        //when the selection is cleared remove the popup content from the side panel.
        popup.on("ClearFeatures", function() {
          dom.byId("featureCount").innerHTML = "Click to select feature(s)";
          registry.byId("leftPane").set("content", "");
          domUtils.hide(dom.byId("pager"));
        });
        //When features are associated with the  map's info window update the sidebar with the new content.
        popup.on("SetFeatures", function() {
          displayPopupContent(popup.getSelectedFeature());
          dom.byId("featureCount").innerHTML = popup.features.length + " feature(s) selected";
          //Enable navigation if more than one feature is selected
          popup.features.length > 1 ? domUtils.show(dom.byId("pager")) : domUtils.hide(dom.byId("pager"));
        });
    } //end initializeSidebar
```

This is what I have for my HTML body:

```
<body class="claro">
        <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false"style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="gutters:false" region="left" style="width: 23%;height:100%;">
                <div id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
                    <div id="featureCount" alt="featureCount">From the search drop-down, select which type you would like to search, then enter an address within Alameda County.</div>
                </div>
                <div id="leftPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="google-maps">
            </div>
            <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
                <div id="search" placeholder="Choose from the dropdown" title !important="Choose from the dropdown"></div>
            </div>

        </div>        
    </body>
```

How do I get my map to work in the sidebar?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Can you add some details to your question--maybe a bit more of your HTML; any error messages that you might be seeing in the Dev Tools console, etc.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi added more of my HTML